# Changing attribute / element style by name

Tags: javascript, css

I m actually trying to modify a style changing the tag element / the attribute name with another one to apply to the on another item.

Example :

I need to pass this :

```
a{
 color:red;
}
```

to

```
p{
color : red;
}
```

With pure javascript.

Does it exist a way allowing me to do this, **without duplicating my style with** :

```
document.getElementById("element2").style = document.getElementById("element1").style;
```

EDIT : I need to pass "a" styles to "p" styles removing "a" styles.

Comment: Should write in the better way to indicate that after the pass, the style of "a" will disappear

Comment: If you want to change the style, why not use classes and swap the class names via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

After some researches, I have come to a conclusion that you should approach this problem by changing class (add, remove), which will eventually affect your style

[Live Version](http://jsfiddle.net/mankinchi/yhL5aLjp/)

```
document.getElementById("blue").className += " " + document.getElementById("red").className;
```

By using className, you will have the access to the class the object currently have and modify it.

**jQuery verision**

If you are using jQuery, the better option would be using *toggleClass*, *addClass*, *removeClass*

Comment: Is in element2 will be not only one color property?

Comment: I want to pass all "a" styles to "p" styles, removing "a" styles

Comment: @Alexander multiple color would be ok. I will do the jsfiddle for this :)

Comment: @Skahrz so do you want to duplicate your style or not? Since in your question, you state that you don't want to

Comment: Please do not link to w3schools!

Comment: @atornblad why is it?

Comment: @Skahrz have a look :)

Comment: Because w3schools is generally considered to be one of the worst possible source of information. Please link directly to official documentation sources instead, like W3C or MDN. http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
var element1 = document.getElementById("element1"),
    element2 = document.getElementById("element2"),
    completeStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element1, null).cssText;

    element2.style.cssText = completeStyle;
```

**Note**: not supported by IE